# how to check that json string is valid or not?

Tags: android

Is it possible to check whether json string is valid or not? The string is as follows which I want to check

```
{
    "bakso-roso-n'deso__-6.19_106.77":
    {"Latitude":"-6.185488","Longitude":"106.77366","Distance":"90.89210930799594"},
    "print-point-duri-kepa__-6.19_106.77":
    {"Latitude":"-6.18599544813468","Longitude":"106.77267676603988647","Distance":"118.9849339548274"},
    "apartment-menara-kebun-jeruk__-6.19_106.78":
    {"Latitude":"-6.185303767096767007","Longitude":"106.7752222767679179","Distance":"247.8816947606767"},
    "ranch-market---pesanggrahan__-6.19_106.77":
    {"Latitude":"-6.1876130647tg7t72002","Longitude":"106.77343661177","Distance":"294.4255786871916"}
}
```

Comment: Parse it and see if it parses? Do you mean programmatically, or just in general?

Comment: Now copy and paste your json [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]you can use the link http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2):

I use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate my json

Answer (score 0):

I have got a better online json parser. It even tells at which point json is wrong. and tells at which point what thing is missing.

you need not click on validate. it automatically checks error at runtime. it's really cool. try it :)

http://json.parser.online.fr/